# Refactoring two identical functions that work on different HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, loops, refactoring

I have two functions that are identical except one has a loop that changes colors to one set of html td tags and the other functions changes colors to another set of td html tags. They are:

```
for (var i = 0; i < medHardSquares.length; i++)
for (var i = 0; i < easySquares.length; i++)
```

Is there a way to pass arguments and have one single function handle the tags based on the argument sent in? Can I make it like:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < arg.length; i++)
```

Comment: You have two different sets of `td` tags and would like to give these a random color using one loop, am I correct?

Comment: yes thats correct

Comment: you seem to have the right idea in your post - what are you getting stuck on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if the process for changing colors are truly identical, and the structure of  your variables are the same, ie HTMLCollection/Array of td elements, just pass either td collection into your function

```
function changeColors(squares){
  for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++){
     squares[i].style.backgroundColor = whateveColor;
  }
}

changeColors(medHardSquares);
changeColors(easySquares);
```

Comment: facepalm, thank you, it's been a while since I've coded haha